# ¿Cómo añado un archivo a una version y publicar esta version?

Tags: git, github, git-push

he creado una version de git pero deseo añadir un archivo modificado a una version ya creada donde se encontraba este antes de ser modificado y subirlo en mi repositorio en GITHUB.
PSDT: si se enlazar git a github y lo demas, mi unico problema es colocar un archivo modificado en una version ya hecha.

mis comandos :
git add (nombre de archivo)
git commit -ammend -m "nombre de version"
git push -u origin master (ME APARECE ERROR)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quita el -u y haz el push

Comment: ya coloce "push - " y "git push -" , no funciona

Comment: No hace falta que usaras una imagen para el problema. Podrías haber puesto el texto de la consola (incluso hay personas que lo habrían formateado por tí si no lo sabes hacer y así podrías ver cómo se hace). En todo caso, si ya habías empujado una rama al remoto y luego enmendaste un commit y lo quieres empujar en la misma rama, git, por defecto, no te va a dejar hacerlo ya que, para él, hay una bifurcación en la historia. Si estás seguro de que quieres empujar la rama como la tienes, usa `-f` en el push. Debería funcionar sin problemas a menos que la rama esté _protegida_ en el remoto.